# How to make table td take the width of its content

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsiveness

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zvmcyp4w/

```
.wide {
  width: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
}
.narrow {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightpink;
}
.table-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

<div class="wide">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Many words</>
        <td>word</td>
        <td>oneword</td>
        <td>onemoreword</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="narrow">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Many words</>
        <td>word</td>
        <td>oneword</td>
        <td>onemoreword</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm simulating a responsive layout with "wide" and "narrow" containing the same table.

In "narrow" you can scroll left and right.

If the content of a cell is made out of multiple words, like the first cell, it automatically breaks into lines.

What I'm looking for is to avoid breaking the line and have the cell expand horizontally to accommodate its content, given that the content is dynamic therefore no fixed widths or min-widths allowed.

Ideally a clean CSS only solution would be great, I already know how to solve it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want multiple words not to expand on multiple rows? You can use `white-space` property

```
.narrow table td{
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexix/zvmcyp4w/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `white-space: pre` to the table cells:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvmcyp4w/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust the `td` styles to include `white-space: nowrap;`

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Also, a couple of your `td` elements had malformed closing tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/zvmcyp4w/2/